# Display filter by price on layered navigation

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price, layered-navigation, filter

I have a problem with Magento. Probably I have misconfigured it. The price filter on layered navegation doesn't show. In `Configuration → Catalog → Catalog → Layered Navigation` i have `Display Product Count → ON` and `Price Navigation Step Calculation → Automatic (equalize price ranges)`. Do I need anything else to configure or what?

Comment: Make sure that the price attribute is set to be used in layered navigation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the admin panel go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes. Find the attribute with code 'price'. Select the row. Then go to Properties->Front end properties. There is a drop down "Use In Layered Navigation" and another one "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation". Adjust these two as you like.