# Show date attribute in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, date

How to show "date" attribute in Layered Navigation in Frontend?

Comment: have you found any solutions for this date attribute then please share!

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`. Find the attribute with code `date`. Select the row. Then go to `Properties->Front end properties`. There is a drop down `Use In Layered Navigation` .

follow this [Display filter by price on layered navigation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14088/display-filter-by-price-on-layered-navigation)

Comment: For date attribute, Use In Layered Navigation is set to No by default and is not editable.

Comment: `Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to show product listing according to dates on product listing page. How can I do that? Do I need to create a module for that or is there some alternate way to do that?

Comment: you want to add like price filter?? and surely you have to create a module for that. or get some free layered navigation module and change it.

Comment: Yes, you got me correct. I want that.

Comment: which magento version you are working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33563/discussion-between-rajan-faldu-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: `https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html`
`https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html`
from these you can get idea how to add you own filter

Comment: @QaisarSatti i want to add date filter add in layered navigation you have any idea for that?

Comment: @RakeshDonga you talking about magento 1 or magento 2

Comment: @QaisarSatti i am talking about magento1

Comment: @RakeshDonga follow my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144440/quantity-as-filter-in-layered-navigation/157814#157814

Comment: @QaisarSatti but i want to add date filter not quantity filter

Comment: @RakeshDonga following this you can add a date filter